# Details.html partial template is not fetching JSON properties..wrong scope?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am teaching myself AngularJS based on the following [documentation/tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01). I've slightly tweaked it for my own project. I got everything working except I can't figure out why the 'symbol-detail.html' view is not pulling in data from the 'symbol.json' file. I think there's something wrong with the scope?

My [**json file is here**](http://www.ogmda.com/symbols/js/symbols.json). The app code is as follows....

**My template layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="symbolscatApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title ng-bind-template="{{query}}">Symbols catalog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**My controller.js file:**

```
var symbolcatControllers = angular.module('symbolcatControllers', []);

symbolcatControllers.controller('SymbolsListController', ['$scope','$http', 
function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('js/symbols.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.symbols = data;
});
$scope.orderProp = "alpha";//for selection dropdown
}]);

symbolcatControllers.controller('SymbolsDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
function($scope, $routeParams){
$scope.symbolName = $routeParams.symbolName;
}]);
```

**My app.js file:**

```
var symbolscatApp = angular.module('symbolscatApp', [
'ngRoute',
'symbolcatControllers'
]);

symbolscatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/symbols', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/symbol-list.html',
            controller: 'SymbolsListController'
        }).
        when('/symbols/:symbolName', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/symbol-detail.html',
            controller: 'SymbolsDetailController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/symbols'
        });
}]);
```

**My symbol-detail.html view:**

```
    <section class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-8">

        <nav>
            <ul class="pager">
            <li class="previous"><a href="#/"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <img ng-src="../images/icons/{{symbol.shortName}}.png">

        <h1>{{symbol.name}}</h1>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Group</th>
                    <th>keywords</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum sapien a risus pulvinar aliquam.</td>
                    <td>Transportation</td>
                    <td>boat, sea, ocean, water</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        </div><!--/.col-lg-8-->

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <aside>
                <h3>Related</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Symbol1</li>
                    <li>Symbol1</li>
                    <li>Symbol1</li>
                    <li>Symbol1</li>
                </ul>    
            </aside>

            <section>
                <h4>Downloads</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>cheatsheet</li>
                    <li>download file1</li>
                    <li>download file 2</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div><!--/.col-lg-4-->

    </section><!--/.row-->

</div><!--/.container-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the reason your *"Details.html"* (I think you meant `symbol-detail.html`) is not showing the JSON data is because you haven't fetched any data, in the `SymbolsDetailController`.

Try adding a `$get` request like you did in `SymbolsListController`
**Note:** you will need to pass `$http` as a dependency also:

```
symbolcatControllers.controller('SymbolsDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 
function($scope, $routeParams, $http){

$scope.symbolName = $routeParams.symbolName;

// this will fetch data and attach to $scope.symbols
$http.get('js/symbols.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.symbols = data;
});

// Pseudo code for getting the particular item and attaching to $scope
// 
// create property to hold individual item
// $scope.symbolItem = $scope.symbols[$routeParams.symbolName]

}]);
```

This will make the all JSON encoded items available to the `$scope.data` property in your `SymbolsDetailController`.

#### Obtaining a single item from the collection of items

Im assuming in your `symbol-detail.html` view , you want to show the info for a single item, rather than all items.
If you want to then obtain an individual item from the JSON array you will need to pluck it out of the array by the ID passed to `$routeParams` , Ive have added some pseudo code showing this.

You should then be able to bind the `$scope.symbolItem` to your view:

```
<p>{{ $scope.symbolItem.<whatever> }}</p>
```

Comment: Michael, yes, I thought the same as your answer, but I didn't include it in my original question beause it didn't work. however, I just updated it again based on your feedback [live link](http://ogmda.com/symbols/index.html#/symbols/Air%20Balloon) and you can see that it doesn't work. Yes, I am working with 'symbol-detail.html'. I'll keep thinking it through...but if you have any other ideas, let me know.

Comment: I made a typo in the code I posted, I didnt wrap `$http` in quotes when I passed into the controller. Ive updated my answer, you will need to update your code

Comment: Also, as @codeepic pointed out, your `$scope.<properties>` need to match with the `{{  }}` expressions in the view. i.e. if you want to show `$scope.symbolName` in the view then the expression needs to be `{{ symbolName }}`. you are using `$scope.symbols` and `$scope.symbolName` in the controller but `{{ symbol.name }}` in the view

Comment: The symbol details view will be shown when the URL hash fragment matches '/symbols/:symbolName', where :symbolName is a variable part of the URL. To construct the symbol details view, Angular will use the symbol-detail.html template and the SymbolsDetailController controller.

I also fixed the typo you mentioned--still doesn't work:( But, thanks because I made that same mistake.

Comment: Everything is close now, but you are still not binding the `$scope` controller variables to the view properly. You currently have this code  `$scope.symbols = data` in the controller. add this code {{ symbols }} anywhere in the `symbol-detail.html` and reload. hopefully you will see how the binding works its actually simple

Comment: when I do {{symbols}} in the view it gives me an array of objects. Obviously I tried {{symbol.name}} but that didn't work.

Comment: Great, I think that answers your question of *"details partial template not fetching JSON"*. If you want to know how to access the properties etc, try figure for yourself or ask another question. If the solution I provided answered your question you can click big tick so other people who might have the same problem can know the correct solution.

Comment: I was able to get it all fixed once I understood how the $routeProvider works. I had to rewrite some of the controller code. THanks, lets mark this closed.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that json data is visible in the controller?
Second: you are fetching an array of objects, but nowhere in your view,
 you try to access it. You are trying to show {{symbol.name}} but in the "SymbolsDetailController" you have `$scope.symbolName = $routeParams.symbolName;`

Try to run `ng-repeat="symbol in symbols"` and show details like `symbol.name`, `symbol.group`, `symbol.description` like in the following code:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat='symbol in symbols'>
  <p>{{symbol.name}}</p>
  <p>{{symbol.group}}</p>
  <p>{{symbol.description}}</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just added the $http service for the json file to the 'SymbolsDetailController' controller. But, it still won't pull the data into the 'symbol-detail.html' partial. See [here](http://ogmda.com/symbols/index.html#/symbols/Air%20Balloon).

Comment: btw i was able to run the ng-repeat directive with no problems